# Rasa Bangla Chatbot

Tags: nlp, rasa-nlu, rasa

[6]:  !{python} -m spacy download bn_core_web_md
     !{python} -m spacy link bn_core_web_md bn --force;

Output:✘ No compatible model found for 'bn_core_web_md' (spaCy v2.1.8).

✘ Can't locate model data
The data should be located in bn_core_web_md

*I want to load Bangla data,Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Spacy does not support Bengali at the moment. You can check the list of supported models here - https://spacy.io/models.